# Tabs are not working properly after including angular in my template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i'm having problem with tabs since i have included AngularJS in my HTML bootstrap template. I'm working with [Flatastic template](http://velikorodnov.com/html/flatastic/features_shortcodes.html). Now i don't know how to proceed further.

Let me show you my html code

```
<div>
    <!--tabs navigation-->
    <nav>
        <ul role="tablist">
            <li role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true">
               <a href="#tab-1" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
            <li role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tab-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false">
                <a href="#tab-2" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Tab 2</a>
            </li>
            <li role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tab-3"  aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false">
                <a href="#tab-3" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Tab 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--tabs content-->
    <section class="tabs_content shadow r_corners">
        <div id="tab-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
            <p>BLABLABLA</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <p>BLABLABLA </p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <p>BLABLABLA</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

As you can see tabs are clickable with a tag `<a href="#tab3" ...` but the problem is that AngularJs takes over link and redirects you to some other page. I believe that those tabs are written in Jquery and now i'm wondering what i need to do to make it working as intended.
If you need any additional information, please let me know and i will provide.

+
Bonus point for user who finds any articles, tutorials or any kind of informations regarding what to watch out or do when you include Angular on Bootstrap templates and how to face those problems

Comment: You could format your code for better readability..

Comment: i have removed some unnecessary data from HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this angularJS component example to create `tabs`

angular file (.js)

```
angular.module('components', [])

  .directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {},
      controller: function($scope, $element) {
        var panes = $scope.panes = [];

        $scope.select = function(pane) {
          angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
            pane.selected = false;
          });
          pane.selected = true;
        }

        this.addPane = function(pane) {
          if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
          panes.push(pane);
        }
      },
      template:
        '<div class="tabbable">' +
          '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
              '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
            '</li>' +
          '</ul>' +
          '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
  })

  .directive('pane', function() {
    return {
      require: '^tabs',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: { title: '@' },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsController) {
        tabsController.addPane(scope);
      },
      template:
        '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
  })
```

this link can give more ideas. Look at the last example in this page https://angularjs.org/

Comment: can you provide some examples, please

Comment: An alternative. Maybe this tutorial can help you. https://www.grobmeier.de/bootstrap-tabs-with-angular-js-25112012.html

Comment: already tried, got error $(...).tab is not a function. Problem is because that template is using a lot of Jqeury code, now i don't know how to proceed further. Should i rewrite all JQuery code or what?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that AngularJs take this as a routing : href="#tab-1".

```
 <li role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true">
           <a href="#tab-1" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Tab 1</a>
 </li>
```

You can try this, I think it is the best solution to work with Bootstrap and AngularJs in a same project without any conflicts : [Angular Ui Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

It is very simple to use, that is a tutorial about an example and the plunker of tab with it :  [tabs with angular ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: yes i saw that example, but it was not working for me. What i have learned is, that including angular in already created templates with a lot of jquery is pain in ass. Thank you for suggestions!

Comment: i already solved the problem with help of upper code, so i will move forward to other problems.  ;) thx for enthusiasm anyway